# Linux SED RegEx replace, but keep wildcards

Tags: regex, linux, sed, regex-group

If I have a string that contains this somewhere (Foo could be anything):

```
<tag>Foo</tag>
```

How would I, using SED and RegEx, replace it with this:

```
[tag]Foo[/tag]
```

My failed attempt:

```
echo "<tag>Foo</tag>" | sed "s/<tag>\(.*\)<\\/tag>/[tag]\1[\\/tag]"
```

Comment: start by simplifying your regex life by using an alternate character to delimit s/s/r/, like `s@....@.....@`. Some sed's need to be warned that your using an alternate (for just the first char), so `s\@...@...@`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is missing the terminating `/`

```
$ echo "<tag>Foo</tag>" | sed "s/<tag>\(.*\)<\\/tag>/[tag]\1[\\/tag]/"
[tag]Foo[/tag]
```

Answer (score 2):

With this you can replace all types of tags and don't have to be tag specific.

```
$echo "<tag>Foo</tag>" | sed "s/[^<]*<\([^>]*\)>\([^<]*\)<\([^>]*\)>/[\1]\2[\3]/"
```

hope this helps.